# Javascript - Creating a switch case based on the ID of the button clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a virtual keyboard which outputs a sound (Morse Code) based on the button clicked.

Keyboard layout was created using HTML buttons as shown below:

```
<button id="q">Q</button>
<button id="w">W</button>
<button id="e">E</button>
<button id="r">R</button>
<button id="t">T</button>
<button id="y">Y</button>
```

How can I create a switch statement which plays audio based on the ID of the button clicked? And are there better alternatives to switch statements in this case?

So far I have come up with the following JS code but it does not seem to be working:

```
document.getElementByTagName("button").onclick(){
    switch(){
        case "a":
            a.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "A";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = ".-";
            break;
        case "b":
            b.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "B";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = "-...";
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Link to full project: https://github.com/Grexus/Personal-Projects/tree/master/Morse%20Code-er

Comment: Thats invalid syntax for [`onclick`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: `document.getElementByTagName("button")` should be `document.getElementsByTagName("button")` (note the extra `s` character to create 'getElements'). Reference: [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName`); without wishing to be offensive you may need to refresh your memory of - or increase your familiarity with - JavaScript.

Comment: No offence taken, I'm still in the learning phase. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo here `document.getElementByTagName`, it will be `document.getElementsByTagName`. Note the `s`

Also instead of switch case , object mapping can be used, since switch case bump up the complexity

```js
// using spread syntax to convert collection to array
// forEach is an array method
[...document.getElementsByTagName("button")].forEach(function(item) {
  // adding eventListener to the elements
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // calling the methods
    // this.id will be the id of the clicked button
    // there is a method in the object by same name, which will be trigger
    obj[this.id]();

  })
})

var obj = {
  q: function() {
    console.log('q')
  },
  w: function() {
    console.log('w')
  },
  e: function() {
    console.log('e')
  },
  r: function() {
    console.log('r')
  },
  t: function() {
    console.log('t')
  },
  y: function() {
    console.log('y')
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="q">Q</button>
<button id="w">W</button>
<button id="e">E</button>
<button id="r">R</button>
<button id="t">T</button>
<button id="y">Y</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution....

```js
function makeSound(id){
    switch(id){
        case "a":
            a.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "A";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = ".-";
            break;
        case "b":
            b.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "B";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = "-...";
            break;
        case "q":
            //q.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "q";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = "-...";
            break;
        case "q":
            //q.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "q";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = "-...";
            break;
        case "w":
            //q.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "w";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = "-...";
            break;
        case "e":
            //q.play();
            document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = "e";
            document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = "-...";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="q" onClick="makeSound(this.id)">Q</button>
<button id="w" onClick="makeSound(this.id)">W</button>
<button id="e" onClick="makeSound(this.id)">E</button>
<button id="r" onClick="makeSound(this.id)">R</button>
<button id="t" onClick="makeSound(this.id)">T</button>
<button id="y" onClick="makeSound(this.id)">Y</button>

<p id="letter"></p>
<p id="morse"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the above! This is what I was originally going for! Seems I need to familiarise myself more with the 'this' keyword. However, it seems like the best solution is to try the 'forEach' method.

Answer (score 1):

you can listen to even keydown on your page then switch the result 
a,b,c,d etc ..

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;
  console.log('keydown event\n\n' + 'key: ' + keyName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch on the ID, just get the ID from the element:
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach(element => 
      element.onclick = e => {
        switch(element.id) {
          // cases here
        }
      };
    });

Also, note that to properly apply the `click` event, you'll have to convert the list to an array and loop through, applying the click event one at a time (unlike jQuery).

However, for something like this, I would probably build an object with the various needed things and then just read it back out:

```
const keys = {
  a: { // id
     tone: a, // element
     letter: "A",
     morse: ".-"
  },
  // all the letters
}
```

Then you can just get the right value without a switch, making it much more compact:

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach(element => 
     element.onclick = e => {
         const key = keys[element.id];
         key.tone.play();
         document.getElementById("letter").innerHTML = key.letter;
         document.getElementById("morse").innerHTML = key.morse;
     };
  });
```

Here is a partial example:

```js
const keys = {
  a: {
    tone: { play: () => console.log('play A') }
  },
  b: {
    tone: { play: () => console.log('play B') }
  }
};


Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach(element => {
         element.onclick = e => {
             const key = keys[element.id];
             key.tone.play();
         };
      });
```

```html
<button id="a">A</button>
<button id="b">B</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of the clicked element by accessing the `target` field on the `event` parameter.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#container > *').forEach(v => {
  v.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="q">Q</button>
  <button id="w">W</button>
  <button id="e">E</button>
  <button id="r">R</button>
  <button id="t">T</button>
  <button id="y">Y</button>
</div>
```